# How to serve all requests from a subpath through the same PHP file?

Tags: php, heroku, nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi

I'm pulling out my hair trying to get the following setup to work on my machine and on Heroku:

- main pages are PHP files residing in the document root
- there's an API under `root/api`. All requests to `/api/*` should be forwarded to its gateway file (`api/index.php`).

Locally I got this to work with a different conf file (below), but on Heroku nothing is working correctly. The best I could figure out was this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    index index.php;
}
location ~ ^/api/(.+) {
    try_files /api/index.php /api/index.php;
}
location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    try_files @heroku-fcgi @heroku-fcgi;
}
```

If I try to use rewrite, it complains of an infinite loop. If I try to set the gateway script as `index` and use `try_files` with their FCGI location, I get 404 - as there's nothing under the `/api` folder besides that script.
Using `try_files` and pointing the script directly makes Heroku send the .php file directly for download instead of interpreting it. How can I make it be interpreted, and still override all other `/api/*` requests?

---

Conf file working on my local machine:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   devshop.dev;

    index index.php;
    root  /home/myself/dev/developer-shop/www/;

    location ~ ^/api(/|$) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    }

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your local machine PHP scripts are handled within their respective location block. On your target machine the `/api/` location performs an internal rewrite which is then *expected* to be handled by the php block.

Regex location blocks are ordered so that `/api/index.php` keeps hitting the `/api/` location block - hence the redirection loop.

Either reverse the order of the regex location blocks or more simply, use a prefix location block with a rewrite:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^ /api/index.php;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.